# How can I load data from a json file into a Cassandra database?

Tags: json, cql, cqlsh

I should load data of a json file in Cassandra, but I can't find the right commands. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of inserting an individual json-formatted entry:

```
INSERT INTO NerdMovies JSON '{"language": "several", "country": "new zealand", "main_actor": "Cate Blanchett", "movie": "lord of the rings", "director": "peter jackson", "year": "2001"}';
```